# Insert border in responsive table

Tags: css, responsive-design

I found a tutorial about responsive-table

https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

My problem is I don't know how to insert a border between the label and td when it is resize(mobile version).

how can I do that?
thanks in advance..

Comment: A border right on the ::before I expect

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/311e8f99/ here is the sample code after I put a margin-right.. I like to see it as a 2 column bordered table.. but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

css

```
/* 
Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
*/
table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
/* Zebra striping */
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #eee; 
}
th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}
td, th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
}


@media 
    only screen and (max-width: 760px),
    (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

        /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
        table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
            display: block; 
        }

        /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
        thead tr { 
            position: absolute;
            top: -9999px;
            left: -9999px;
        }

        tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

        td { 
            /* Behave  like a "row" */
            border: none;
      padding-left:50%;
      width:100%;
        }

        td:before { 
            /* Now like a table header */
            position: absolute;
            /* Top/left values mimic padding */
            width: 40%; 
      margin-top:-7px;
      left:1em;
            padding: 7px 1em 7px 0; 
      border-right: 1px solid Silver; 
        }

        /*
        Label the data
        */
        td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
        td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
        td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
        td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Favorite Color"; }
        td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Wars of Trek?"; }
        td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Porn Name"; }
        td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
        td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Dream Vacation City"; }
        td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "GPA"; }
        td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Arbitrary Data"; }
    }

    /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width : 320px)
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
        body { 
            padding: 0; 
            margin: 0; 
            width: 320px; }
        }

    /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
        body { 
            width: 495px; 
        }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/311e8f99/2/